# How to left-justify content in a second Tailwind CSS grid column, so it stays against the gap between it and 1st column, at all screen sizes?

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid, tailwind-css

How do I left-justify the content in a second Tailwind CSS grid column (green background, with rating stars), so it stays against the gap between it and 1st column (yellow background with blue text)?

I've tried 30 or 40 approaches and am stuck!

As you'll see below, the 2nd column, with green background and rating stars, hugs left and is right up against the gap between it an the 1st column.

As the screen gets wider, the 2nd column (green background) starts pulling right, leaving a bigger and bigger space (black background) between the 1st and 2nd columns (this is the problem I'm trying to solve).

This is a Vue 3 project, with Tailwind CSS 2.2.14

**375px screen width:**
[image: 375px screen width]

**475px screen width:**
[image: 475px screen width]

**575px screen width:**
[image: 575px screen width]

**675px screen width:**

*The white background is a 3rd column that only shows-up at this width and larger. I tried (unsuccessfully) to have it consume all the extra space and push column 2 left, against its gap with column 1.*
[image: 675px screen width]

**775px screen width:**
[image: 775px screen width]

**875px screen width:**
[image: 875px screen width]

**975px screen width:**
[image: 975px screen width]

Here's my code:

```
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-3 gap-4 md:gap-2 bg-black justify-end"> <!-- BEGIN the main div, with the black background -->

        <div class="col-span-1 place-content-end sm:px-3 max-w-max whitespace-nowrap bg-yellow-300"> <!-- BEGIN 1st column, with text + yellow background, on left -->
            <p class="text-zagblue text-base sm:text-base font-bold text-right align-bottom mb-5">Xxxxxxx rating:</p>
            <p class="text-zagblue text-base sm:text-base font-bold text-right align-bottom mb-5">Yyyyy & yyyy rating:</p>
            <p class="text-zagblue text-base sm:text-base font-bold text-right align-bottom mb-5">Qqqqqqqq(s) rating:</p>
            <p class="text-zagblue text-base sm:text-base font-bold text-right align-bottom mb-5">Wwwwwww rating:</p>      
        </div> <!-- END 1st column, with text + yellow background, on left -->
        
        <div class="col-span-1 place-content-start max-w-max whitespace-nowrap bg-green-200"> <!-- BEGIN 2nd column, with stars and green background -->
          <div class="mb-4 align-top">
            <div>         
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="non_rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
              </div>  
          </div>

          <div class="mb-4 align-top">
            <div>         
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="non_rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="non_rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="non_rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
              </div>  
          </div>

          <div class="mb-4 align-top">
            <div>         
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="non_rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="non_rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
              </div>  
          </div>

          <div class="mb-4 align-top">
            <div>         
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
                <fa icon="star" id="rating_star" size="lg" class="mr-1.5"/>
              </div>  
          </div>
          
        </div> <!-- END 2nd column with stars and green background-->

        <div class="col-span-0 sm:col-span-1 flex-grow bg-white"> <!-- BEGIN "junk" 3rd column, with white background (unsuccessfully tried to make this take all unused space) -->
          <p></p>
        </div> <!-- END BEGIN "junk" 3rd column, with white background -->


      </div> <!-- END the main div, with the black background -->
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It seems like ```justify-self-start``` in the 2nd column's div class should've done the trick, but it didn't work. Link to TailwindCSS docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-self

Comment: Hi, it seems your code example is missing the first opening div where grid and the background are called.

Comment: Thanks @JHeth. I just added that missing first line.

Comment: So it's a bit hard to tell what you're trying to achieve since you only provided screens of the problem and did not really describe what the solution should look like. But removing `max-w-max` from the green container will allow it to take up the whole width allotted to it.

Comment: The question title and first paragraph describe exactly what I'm trying (and failing) to achieve. Thanks for your time and suggestion to remove ```max-w-max```, but what you describe is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think I get it. But not possible with default Tailwind grid utilities. They're designed for making uniform grids. The reason you see this problem is not because col 2 is not all the way to the left (it is in it's column) but because column 1's width creates black space after column 1's content. You can use inspector in Chrome to see the grid lines.

Maybe you're looking for something like [this](https://play.tailwindcss.com/HZSx902raF) which can be done with a single inline style, or you could add a Tailwind utility for it but that would be overkill if it's only used once.

Comment: Thanks @JHeth, I'll go through your suggestion carefully later today.

Comment: @JHeth, I'm not looking to make a non-uniform grid - I'm looking to have the far-left column content (yellow background) justify to its right, and a 2nd column (green background) justify its content to its left, so the content for each column is hugging the common gap between them regardless of screen size.

Comment: In that case all you need to do is add `justify-self-end` to the first column, the second column is already hugging the left side. Here's a Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/mBoJBBPwEc

Comment: @JHeth, That works. THANK YOU! Please write your response as a clear answer that will help others and I'll mark it as correct and award the 50 point bounty I created.

Comment: Happy to help! Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance the first column and second column have equal width. At larger screen sizes it looks like there's space between the gap and the start of the second column content. Using dev tools you can see the opposite is the case, the first column is not filling the width of it's grid cell causing blank space.

All that needs to be added is `justify-self-end` on the content of the first grid column so that it hugs the right side of it's grid cell leaving only the gap between the 2 columns.